# To make a React app with SmartCard authentication, Shoud I use pkcs11?

Tags: reactjs, smartcard, pkcs#11, contactless-smartcard, substrate

I'm building a Webapp(likely to be react) with backend of Substrate(Blockchain framework in Rust). And I want to allow users to sign and verify their account with Smartcard.

Pkcs15-tool worked perfectly with the type of Smartcard im planning to use and I heard pkcs11 is the api meant for software development instead of pkcs15-tool.(correct me if I'm wrong)

How can I implement Smartcard authentication with React web application? Is pkcs11 the right way to go? Im really a beginner in Smart Card.

Comment: Check if this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55757349/9659885

Answer (score 0):

Yes, often PKCS#11 can be the answer. PKCS#11 is platform independent, standardized middleware to talk to *cryptographic tokens*. Cryptographic tokens are tokens that hold key (and other) objects, where the key objects can be *used* but not extracted. Smart cards are one form of cryptographic token, a HSM is another.

A key used for authenticating can obviously stored and used for signature generation through PKCS#11. Similarly the certificates that are commonly build around the *public* key can be retrieved using PKCS#11. There are of course other standards such as OpenPGP and PGP compatible cards that could be used. Proprietary protocols are an option as well, but you'd have to think up a pretty complex one to use multiple authentication devices. That said, a higher level authentication protocol might just what you need.

Unfortunately I don't know how to implement this using React without researching it myself, and asking us to help you design / implement a system for a particular runtime is much to broad for StackOverflow anyway.